# Emmet snippet for html classes inherited from parent for easier scss

Tags: html, sass, emmet

Is there an emmet snippet or another way to achive class autocomplition like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent__child"></div>
</div>
```

By typing
.&__child
(it would work similar to just typing dot to create a div with a class but with added parent class)
This snippet would help with scss nesting.

I tried this snippet:

```
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "&": "<div class=\"$TM_CURRENT_LINE/^\\.(.*?)&(-.*?)?(.*?)$/${1}${2:+-${2:substr(1)}}${3:+ $3}/\">$0</div>"
    }
  }
}
```

and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There’s a BEM processor for something similar: https://docs.emmet.io/filters/bem/

Note that these docs are obsolete, in current Emmet versions you have to enable `bem` option in plugin preferences (depends on editor you’re using)